# Finding Linear Trend Across Multiple Columns At Once

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I'm looking to find linear trends across multiple columns at once.

I have a data frame goes across numerous columns and would like to find the linear trend down for each column all at once, and I have attempted to use `numpy.polyfit` and `scipy.linregress` but having multiple columns instead of just one is causing problems

I first created a `x` vector of just the length of the columns to use as an `x` variable

```
    x = np.arange(0, len(data))
```

And then used that in `polyfit` and `scipy.linregress`

```
    z = np.polyfit(x,data,1)
```

And also:

```
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,data)
```

Neither attempt works, at least not well. The `numpy` attempt returns an array that doesn't make too much sense:

```
    array([[ 2.41486068e-01,  1.44953560e+01, -2.13374613e+01,
         2.96418989e+01,  3.22187822e+01, -2.31909185e+01,
         1.29256966e+01,  3.00044995e+03,  5.29339525e+02,
         1.17439628e+02,  2.14332301e+02,  5.53914345e+02,
         2.01359443e+03,  3.85400413e+03,  2.73097523e+03,
         4.36991434e+03,  4.65668318e+03,  1.09214809e+04,
         1.22903880e+04,  4.54465470e+04,  1.44244135e+05,
         4.44253437e+04,  3.97449362e+05,  4.50699857e+06],
       [ 2.55029240e+01,  1.04122807e+02,  6.85701754e+02,
         1.13766082e+02, -5.26374269e+01,  1.26212281e+03,
         1.65853801e+02, -1.03461579e+04, -7.30163743e+02,
         4.51048538e+03,  8.33842105e+02,  1.39311696e+03,
        -3.93859649e+01, -1.13257018e+04, -7.10956725e+03,
        -1.63806608e+04, -1.89128070e+04, -3.52064211e+04,
         3.22219240e+04,  2.08106906e+05, -2.73555982e+05,
         5.78638579e+05, -1.72544502e+06, -1.36054242e+07]])
```

While the `scipy` attempt errors out (it obviously doesn't make sense to have multiple `Y` values, but hey gotta try somethin')

What I would **love** and am looking for is an elegant way to find a linear trend down all the columns at once and get an output for that which the length of the columns I have.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: what is your `data` shape ?

Comment: (18, 24) ie 24 columns and would like to find the linear trend down the 18 rows for each column

Comment: i wonder why `The numpy attempt returns an array that doesn't make too much sense` ? `numpy.polyfit` with `order=1` will return 2 values `a` and `b`, which are the coefficients of linearization: `y = a*x+b`. your result is a 2x24 array, whose columns are outputs of `polyfit` of each `data`'s column. what is the exact output do you want ? (a short example of `data` and desired `z` would be great)

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand. I was just expecting an array and output for the slope coefficient and not the intercept. That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!